# Include server-side javascript in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

i'm converting in PHP5 a quite old ASP project that was using a lot of server-side javascript.

is there a way to use that code or i'll have to rewrite everything in PHP?

**EDIT**
this is how the code is embedded in ASP
`<!-- #include file=helper.js -->`

snippet of my helper.js
`<script language=javascript runat=server>

      //here are the functions

</script>`

then in ASP is see that functions are called as usual ie
`response.write myJsfunction()`

btw, if i have to rewrite the code, i'll do on my own, not using any software

Comment: If you would be so kind as to embellish your question with some examples and give some indication of how much JavaScript you have and what it does, I may be able to help.

Comment: PhP is quite easy to learn it isn't to diffrent to javascript quite alot has the very same rules applied, its even quite well documented Php.net has a great community, and using google you'll find your solution for sure for whatever problem you might stumble upon, there's no reason for you to use any rewrite code of sorts would just ruin performance for no good reason imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "you need to rewrite everything in PHP" PHP does not as is support Javascript on the server-side in reuseable manner. Also, the automatic code transformations are very klunky: clean up work takes more time than building everything by hand from the beginning.

However, you can run server-side Javascript code with tools like node.js and backbone.js. Mixing with PHP code is no-go though as these projects will provide their own, non-PHP-compatible, web-servers.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean jscript? Have you tried [asp2php](http://asp2php.naken.cc/)?